# Starting issue on a Fiat Uno Fire 1100

Tags: starting, fiat

My car starts normaly 90% of the time. Sometimes when you turn the ignition it just clicks. If I switch it off and turn it again it starts. Sometimes it happens two of three times but then is starts normal. I've even tried ten times and every time it starts normal. Could it be the soleniod or what? Please help

Comment: What year is your car?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the symptoms described, there seems to be trouble with sending current to the starter motor. Here are the top suspects:

1. Malfunctioning starter relay switch.

   It could well be that the solenoid inside relay is sticking, preventing the switch on the starter side from closing and turning the engine over. This would explain why sometimes you do not hear the starter relay click (complete silence).
2. Bad ignition switch.

   If the ignition switch isn't completing the circuit to the starter relay, the car won't start. I'm a little skeptical that this is an issue given that the dashboard lights come on when the key is in the 'On' position but it is a distinct possibility.
3. [Failing starter motor](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/19733/675).